# $db.CheckTables('None') in Powershell doesn't continue on after encountering corrupt database

Tags: powershell, dbcc

Probably a noob question but here it goes. So i'm making this backup test script with powershell and i'm displaying the results of DBCC in the console and when $db.CheckTables('None') loops through the database collection and encounters a corrupt database it doesn't continue on checking the rest of the databases. This is my code

```js
foreach($db in $dbs) {

    if ($db.Name.EndsWith("_test")) {
      Write - Host "Checking database:"
      $db.Name - BackgroundColor "Yellow" - ForegroundColor "Black"
      $dbname = $db.Name# database check
      $db.CheckTables('None')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either supress it this way:

```
 $db.CheckTables('None') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

or wrap it in try/catch:

```
try {
  $db.CheckTables('None')
} catch {}
```

Comment: >or wrap it in try/catch:

Alright, that worked. Thanks dude.